# Laptop wireless connection drops ADSL router Internet connection

Tags: wireless-networking, adsl

I have a laptop, when I try to connect it to the Internet using wireless connection it doesn't get connected and the wireless router (SMC) drops the ADSL Internet connection, and I have to reboot the router to get the Internet connection back.

***Notes:***

1- When I use **the same laptop** to get connected to the Internet using the **same router (SMC)** but instead of using wireless connection I use **the cable**, it **gets connected to the Internet normally**.

2- When I use **another laptop** to get connected to the Internet using the **same router (SMC)**, **it gets connected to the Internet normally** (wireless connection and cable).

3- When I try to get connected to the Internet using **the same laptop** but with **another router (D-Link)**, it **gets connected normally** (wireless connection and cable).

So, what's the problem?!

Thanks.

Comment: Is the SMC a modem+router thing?

Comment: I think more information about the problem is needed. What exact model of router are you using ? What is the configuration of the dhcp client (laptop) and the configuration of the DHCP Server (router), ranges, are you using static IPs on some other equipment ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is usually the router. Even most of the expensive ones are cheaply made.

Check if it is running the latest firmware, and consider doing a factory reset of some kind.

Comment: @Simon Sheehan, yes it is.  

The most thing that let me keeps wondering is why when I use another laptop to get connected to the Internet using the same router (SMC), it gets connected to the Internet normally (wireless connection and cable)?!!! although the configuration on the two laptops are the same.

Answer (score 0):

I think, your **Wireless Network Connection** `SSID` password might be wrong.

Can you try by deleting the existing `SSID` and connect once again by entering the correct password?

## STEPS TO DO:

1. Go to `Control Panel\Network and Internet\Manage Wireless Networks`
2. Delete the existing Wireless Network Connection
3. Access the actual one and enter the correct password

Comment: No, the SSID password is correct because I tried to enter a wrong password to connect but it didn't work out.

Comment: Ok but can you delete the existing one and access the actual one?

Comment: There is no existing one, Windows didn't create any SSID.

Comment: I mean, if we access any `wireless network connection` then windows will store `SSID` & `password` under **Manage Wireless Network** and also let me know which OS are you using?

Comment: The OS is Windows 7, and it didn't store any SSID because it didn't connect to the router.